# BeautifulSoup 'href' list that is giving ambiguous TypeErrors?

Tags: python, unicode, types, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape urls from a webpage. Everything is going good, until some of the urls have non-ascii characters in them.

```
requests.get('http://www.reddit.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)

urls = [i.get('href') for i in soup.findAll('a') if
        'keyword' in str(i.get('href'))]
```

The list comprehension will return an `UnicodeError`.
So I thought to separate this list comprehension into two parts instead:

```
urls = [i.get('href') for i in soup.findAll('a')]

urls = [i.encode('utf-8') for i in urls]
```

This is when I got an `AttributeError`, saying that the items were `NoneType`.

I checked their type:

```
print [type(i) for i in urls]
```

Which showed all unicode types.  It seems to say that they are `None` and `unicode` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed the `None` value. I checked `www.reddit.com` and, sure enough, there's:

```
<a name="content"></a>
```

Its href is `None`. Instead of printing all values and search for `None` manually, you could do:

```
urls = [(i, i.get('href')) for i in soup.findAll('a')]
print [u for u in urls if u[1] is None]
```

Comment: i saw the '#content' in the list but, when I checked the type it still show `unicode`. Thanks, i will try this.